# Optimize these 4 methods in 1 method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, optimization, methods

```
const getDate = (id) =>{
  const userId =  info.find(user => user.id === id)
  return userId.date;
 }

 const getValueAtOne = (id) => {
   const userId =  info.find(user => user.id === id)
   if(userId?.value[0]){
   return userId?.value[0]
   }
  
 }
 const getValueAtTwo = (id) => {
  const userId =  info.find(user => user.id === id)
   if(userId?.value[1]){ 
   return userId?.value[1]
   }
 
 }
 const getAllValues = (id) => {
  const userId =  info.find(user => user.id === id)
   if(userId?.value) {
   const arrValue = userId?.roles.map((validData) => {
     return { value: validData, label:validData };
   });
   return arrValue;
 }
 }
```

I have these 4 methods, which I am calling from different places in my code.But i want to optimize my code and want all these methods in a single method, but I cant figure out the best way to do it. first method returns me the date, second one returns the value of array at position 1, third method returns value of array at position 2, and 4th method returns the all the value and convert it in object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a single object like so:

```
const getAll = (id) => {
  const userId = info.find((user) => user.id === id);

  const [valueAtOne, valueAtTwo] = userId?.value ?? [];

  const allValues =
    userId?.value.roles.map((validData) => ({
      value: validData,
      label: validData,
    })) ?? [];

  return {
    allValues,
    valueAtOne,
    valueAtTwo,
  };
};
```

Comment: it gives the following error: objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {valueAtOne, valueAtTwo}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Can i use a switch case or something to fetch values based on conditions. I dont want all the values to be returned at the same time.

Comment: This error related to how you render the value and not to the answer. Also please just ask another question and focus on what you asked.

Comment: but in your answer, I'll get all the values together, I want one value at a time, thats why I have made different methods and calling them from different place. and for the same I asked if I can add the switch or may be the if else condition inside the same method, that returns me different value at different instances.

Comment: You don't have to use all values all together... `getAll(id).valueAtOne` ...